# fread reads empty csv wrongly when there is a numeric colname

Tags: r, data.table, fread

If I have an empty csv file with the headers like this -

```
❯ cat an.csv                                                                                                                                                                                                              10:36:25
a,b,c,d
```

In Rconsole when I fread it I get an empty DT.

```
❯ b = fread('an.csv')

❯ b
Empty data.table (0 rows and 4 cols): a,b,c,d
```

But if I have a numeric header name in one of the cols, fread reads it as -

```
❯ cat another.csv                                                                                                                                                                                                         10:38:10
a,b,3
```

```
❯ bb = fread('another.csv')

❯ bb
   V1 V2 V3
1:  a  b  3
```

Why does fread read it wrongly when there are numeric header names. How do I fix it ? It should be an empty dt reagardless of what the col names are.

Edit:

In addition to the answer, the docs also explain how fread distinguishes between considering the first line as a header line or not -

```
  header: Does the first data line contain column names? Defaults
          according to whether every non-empty field on the first data
          line is type character. If so, or TRUE is supplied, any empty
          column names are given a default name.
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use:

```
fread('another.csv', header = TRUE)
```

Comment: works... but im still confused. If I have to pass `header=T`, that means that its default is `F`. But then how does fread know to read a csv without numeric cols correctly. And why ? Are there cases where the requirement is to read the file with unnamed cols ?

Comment: @leoOrion The default is not `FALSE`, it's "auto". It checks to see if things look like valid column names. Numbers are assumed to be data. See the `?fread` help page.

Comment: Yes saw it in the docs now. Thanks.